# Stepping down safely for knee

Tags: muscle, knees, knee-pain, biomechanics

I had some knee injury while doing a one-legged squat a while ago.  Now, I can comfortably step up, but stepping down stairs is a big problem.

While stepping down, how should I orient my torso to minimize stress on my knee? Do I bend it forward, or backward?

Forward will increase pressure on knee, but backward will increase torque, right?

Comment: Does it hurt to descend stairs while keeping the knee extended (that is, your leg straight), compensating with extra hip movement?

Comment: no, i do f;ex knee a bit . normal downl stair movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping down is always known to cause greater stress to the knee joint than stepping up. Since you have had a recent episode where you did the one legged squat, your knee joint may tend to pain for a few more days while stepping down after which the pain is bound to subside. You can try bending a little backwards while u step down and balance your weight equally on both legs. This way your knee pain may reduce than what it presently is. But if the pain remains static after 2-3 weeks as well it would be wise to see a physical therapist.

Comment: +1, I think the last sentence here is the most valuable.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR: Nobody here can answer your question

If you're experiencing enough pain that you struggle with simple tasks like navigating a set of stairs, you should see a physician. At the very least, they will recommend rest and ice (which you should do in the meantime anyway), and they will probably give you a referral for physical therapy. A physical therapist can give an answer to your question that is tailored to the specific nature of your injury.

If your financial situation or a lack of insurance precludes you from seeing a doctor, then I would once again recommend rest and ice, and avoiding activities that cause pain whenever possible (use an elevator, take weight off of your bad knee by leaning on a *sturdy* railing, etc.).

To answer the question that was actually posed: the knee is a very complex joint - even an expert will need more information than you've provided to give you an answer. Leaning either forward or backward could cause more stress on the injury depending on what the injury actually is.

Comment: have seen orthopedic sprain in ligament side one, told me to just wait it will heal, but to safe side i am asking what put less stress on knee while stepping down, torso in front or back